# Echo text after the last back slash (\') of $value

Tags: php, text, echo

I want to be able to get all the text right after the last back slash ('\') of the $value so i can echo it out as something like this:

```
$value = 'Some Folder\Some Folder\Some Folder\FileName v123.txt';
Outputs Echo: FileName v123.txt

$value = 'Some Folder\Some Folder\Some Folder\Another File Name v210.txt';
Outputs Echo: Another File Name v210.txt

$value = 'Some Folder\Some Folder\FileName v123.txt';
Outputs Echo: FileName v123.txt

$value = 'Some Folder\AnotherFile v210.txt';
Outputs Echo: AnotherFile v210.txt
```

Which PHP functions should i use and how to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo end(explode("\\",$value));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function:

```
$value = 'Some Folder\Some Folder\Some Folder\FileName v123.txt';
echo basename($value);
```

Comment: It won't work with back slash, how can i change the separator from front slash to back slash?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work: http://codepad.org/ZrT0Pg2o. Guess it's enviroment dependent.

Comment: That is happening because the \ in your string is acting as start of escape sequence. What you really need to have in the string is \\.

Comment: @codaddict I just copy pasted your code. Anyway, that is a single quote delimited string so they are read as literal backslashes anyway.

Comment: Also, as you are using \ as the path separator, this would work only on Windows. Linux uses / as path separator and codepad uses Linux.

Comment: @codaddict Yes, that is why I said it must be environment dependent.

Comment: I can't change the slashes as the $value is generated like that and my webhost is linux. anyway `echo end(explode("\\",$value));` works well. thanks for helping though

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of strpos() and substr ().